# Urn problem with return

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> In an urn there are 10 balls. Each ball can be white or black with the same probability. We will draw balls repeatedly with return. Find:
>
> (a) The expected value and variance of black balls in the urn;
>
> (b) The probability that there are only white balls in the urn, if we didn't draw any black ball in the four first draws;
>
> (c) The probability that there are at least two black balls in the urn, if we drew one black ball in the first four draws.

My solution:

(a) There is not defined how many times we will draw balls from the urn and it seems to me as binomial distribution, so EX and varX should be:

$EX=np=\frac{n}{2}$

$varX=np(1-p)=\frac{n}{4}$

(b) Conditional probability

B ... I will not draw black ball = $(\frac{1}{2})^4$

$A  \cap B = (\frac{1}{2})^n$

$P(A | B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^n}{(\frac{1}{2})^4}$

(c)

B ... if we draw only one black ball in first four moves = $\binom{4}{1}(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2})^3$

A ... at least two black balls are in the urn = $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k}(\frac{1}{2})^{k}(\frac{1}{2})^{n-k}$

and then I use conditional probability, right?

Someone told me that this example is on Bayes' theorem, but I cannot see how can I use it here. But also something is wrong in my solution ... could someone give me an advice?

Comment: Your answer to (b) looks implausible if $n\lt 4$ as it gives a conditional probability greater than $1$

Comment: I see, thank you for pointing out the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) This is not about drawing; its about how many black balls are in the urn.

So, yes, this will be a binomial distribution. The number of trials is 10, the success rate is $1/2$ (there is equal and independent probability each of the ten balls is black).

$$X\sim\mathcal{Bin}(10,1/2)$$

(b) $\mathsf P(X=0\mid Y=0)$ where $X$ is the number of black balls in the urn (as above) and $Y$ is the number drawn in four draws with replacement.   $Y$ is binomial conditional on $X$; since in this case the rate of success is dependent on the number of black balls in the urn.  $$Y\mid X~\sim~\mathcal{Bin}(4, x/{10})$$

Then $\mathsf P(Y=0\cap X=x) = (\frac{10-x}{10})^4\binom{10}{x}\frac{1}{2^{10}}$

So $\mathsf P(Y=0\cap X=0)= \tfrac 1{2^{10}}$

$\mathsf P(Y=0) =\tfrac 1{2^{10}10^4}\sum_{x=0}^{10} \binom{10}{x}(10-x)^4  =\frac{407}{4000}$

$\therefore\quad\ldots$

---

(c) Similar to above, but this time: $\mathsf P(X\geq 2\mid Y=1) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(Y=1\cap X\geq 2)}{\mathsf P(Y=1)} \\ = \dfrac{\sum_{k=2}^{10} \binom{10}k k(10-k)^3}{\sum_{j=0}^{10} \binom{10}j j(10-j)^3}$